# fileimage error with null safety using image picker

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

CircleAvatar(
radius: 64.0,
backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
child: CircleAvatar(
radius: 60.0,
//profileImage == null
//                                   ? NetworkImage(userModel!.image.toString())
//                                   : FileImage(profileImage),
backgroundImage: profileImage == null ? NetworkImage(userModel.image.toString()) : FileImage(profileImage),
),
),

try to remove and add '?' and '!' and its still error with null safety

Comment: share your full code

Comment: Can you format your code providing a more detailed description ?

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem with your code is that you try to pass positional parameters to the second `CircleAvatar`. I added the name of the variables, as I anticipated you want it to look. Also, I am not sure what type is the `profileImage`. It should not be a string that is for sure.

Anyway, this is, probably, what you want.

```
  var foregroundImage = profileImage == null && userModel != null ? NetworkImage(
      userModel.image.toString()) : FileImage(profileImage)
  var backgroundImage = profileImage == null && userModel != null ? NetworkImage(
      userModel.image.toString()) : FileImage(profileImage)
  return CircleAvatar(
    radius: 64.0,
    backgroundColor: Theme
        .of(context)
        .scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    child: const CircleAvatar(
      radius: 60.0,
      foregroundImage: foregroundImage,
      backgroundImage: backgroundImage,
    ),
  )
```

Comment: the problem with null safety not what u write.
the problem wth the line 
profileImage == null ?NetworkImage(userModel!.image.toString()) : FileImage(profileImage)

--> giving me syntax error

Comment: Maybe it is because of the `userModel` that could be null. 
I will update the code to reflect a possible null userModel